# Git suddenly stopped working

Tags: authentication, git

On the terminal in Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS I wanted to pull a git repository (which I was working on the last hours). I used

```
git fetch && git pull
```

as all the times before.

The first (`fetch`) actually worked but the second (`pull`) failed though I provide exactly the same credentials.

```
Username for 'https://github.com': XXXXXXXXX
Password for 'https://XXXXXXXXX@github.com':
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 9), reused 15 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
From https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX/chef-repo.git
   55e79f9..4fd7878  master     -> origin/master
Username for 'https://github.com': XXXXXXXXX
Password for 'https://XXXXXXXXX@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX/chef-repo.git'
```

Because I used this procedure multible times the last few hours I wanted to check again if I had maybe a typo in the `pull` procedure. But now I get this error already on the first command though there is no doubt I provide the correct credentials

```
$ git fetch
 Username for 'https://github.com': XXXXXXXXX
 Password for 'https://XXXXXXXXX@github.com':
 remote: Invalid username or password.
 fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX/chef-repo.git'
```

**What can I do to fix this and repair my git behavior on this machine?**

**NOTES:**

- The repository is for [Chef](https://chef.io) on the Chef-Workstation so **removing the folder and clone again is not an option** for me or at least the very last because a lot of stuff is excluded via `.gitignore` and I don't know if e.g. any links could brake.
- **I don't use Two-Factor Authentication.**
- I **didn't change anything** especially not inbetween the two commands.
- I **still can login to Gihub** on the webpage using my credentials.
- **I can fetch/pull from other machines**.

---

I've read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297154/github-invalid-username-or-password) (though I don't use SSH but password authentification) but nothing helped so far.

Here the ouput of `git remote -v`

```
origin  https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/chef-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/chef-repo.git (push)
```

Comment: Do you use two-step authentication on GitHub?

Comment: No I don't. At least until now and for what I know. This suddenly stopped working like 10 mins ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I still don't understand what happened but I solved this now:

In Sourcetree on Windows it still worked. Just for trying I edited my profile and tried to reset the password => Worked before but now it sayd `authentication error`

So I went to the Github webpage, logged into my account (still using this same credentials ?!) and changed my password ... and than I changed it back again.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: this worked for me too

Comment: this did not work for me on Ubuntu. Does anyone has any other solutions ?